# c# Как записать опциональный параметр int?

Tags: c#

Нужно сделать int опциональным параметром. Как это сделать? int не должен быть даже нулём.

```
public string OptionalMethod(string s = "", int i = /*???*/ ) {}
```

Comment: просто укажите значение которое будет использовано по умолчанию: `public string OptionalMethod(string s = "123", int? i = null ) {}`

Comment: Есть у переменной такое свойство - иметь значение. Даже если оно NULL или там Empty. Вот такое значение и сделайте дефолтным.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант использования Nullable values

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

`GetFooBar(int? a, int? b)`
или
`GetFooBar(int? a, Nullable<int> b)`

далее, в теле функции можно проверить

`a.HasValue`

```
public string OptionalMethod(string s = "", int? i) {
  if (i.HasValue)
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Nullable<int> === int?